# Regarding the combination of secondary sources

Tags: discussion

Im currently concidering deleting the question  [Testing Roberts's Law: data request on CEO pay and company characteristics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/14694/testing-robertss-law-data-request-on-ceo-pay-and-company-characteristics).

The reason why is because I use a definition of firm size which comes from a separate paper, which produces the final equation within.

How do you use and combine technical papers in an intelligent way? What are the methods used by those in the community?

Comment: I feel like as long as you explain the methodology of your work (what definition you are using and how it affects the result of the final paper on pg. so and so) then it's fine. Other people seem to think it is a good question, and if you are worried it is not accessible enough, then I suppose there is always room for improvement. :) That, and I don't think referencing multiple technical papers is wrong. Just that maybe we don't have a lot of people who can give an answer on that.

Comment: @KitsuneCavalry Im trying to not be pseudo academic. I dont know if the authors of the papers are in agreement of a definition of firm size.

Comment: Ohhh i see @econjohn in that case maybe just leave it up until you can find time to better define the question? Let's see what other members have to say perhaps.

Comment: @KitsuneCavalry I guess it looks intimidating and needs some reading up on.

Comment: I was hoping the great @Alecos Papadopoulos has some wisdom to share on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

I have a conflict of interest because I have an [accepted answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/17898/2776), so my judgment might not be objective enough. However, this is how I see the question:

- Title:

> Testing Roberts's Law: **data request on CEO pay and company characteristics**

- Main text: A lot of maybe uneccessary content, except for some idea of which firm characteristics you are interested in, in particular **firm size**, plus the actual question:

> Where can I find data on CEO pay and company information?

- Tags: [data-request](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request), [reference-request](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)

Given this info, my answer focuses specifically on CEO pay and firm size data sources available. These two are essentially the two requests that are explicit and/or can be implicitly deduced from the question. Hence, the answer **does address the question**.

From this point of view, I see no particular reason why it should be deleted. Maybe, you can modify it to add the relevant paper. Or maybe, you can reduce it to something like:

> I want to test Roberts Law (link to paper + brief discussion of what this is). Hence, I need firm characteristics like CEO pay and firm size. Where can I find these?

(If your original intention was to get some ideas on how to test it, that is a different question altogether, and not so related to the tags used).

Comment: Ah, I see. Not so bad after all.